# Using groupby in pandas to filter a dataframe using count and column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to clean my dataframe and I am trying to use groupby function. I have `ID` and `event_type` as my columns. I want to get a new dataframe where if there is only one row having a Unique ID then the `event_type` must be `a`. If not then delete that row.

Data looks like this: The `event_type` can be "a" or "b"

```
+-----+------------+
| ID  | event_type |
+-----+------------+
| xyz | a          |
| pqr | b          |
| xyz | b          |
| rst | a          |
+-----+------------+
```

Output:
Since the `ID` `"pqr"` occurs only once (which is the count) and does not have `a` (column value) as the `event_type` the dataframe should convert to the following:

```
+-----+------------+
| ID  | event_type |
+-----+------------+
| xyz | a          |
| xyz | b          |
| rst | a          |
+-----+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your logic within a `groupby`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['xyz', 'pqr', 'xyz', 'rst'],
                   "event_type":['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']})
```

what you are asking is this

```
    df.groupby("ID")\
      .apply(lambda x:  not (len(x)==1 and
                             not "a" in x["event_type"].values))
```

as you can check by printing it. Finally to use this filter you just run

```
df = df.groupby("ID")\
       .filter(lambda x:  not (len(x)==1 and
                               not "a" in x["event_type"].values))\
       .reset_index(drop=True)
```